# android sqlite looping to read and insert

Tags: android, sqlite

```
addressString = 
"BOOKNO= [1] 
From= [ 2011-02-28 07:00:52] 
To= [2011-03-17 07:01:02]
Link= [http://www.example.com]
SINCE= [5] days.
BOOKNO= [2] 
From= [ 2011-03-01 17:55:15] 
To= [2011-03-30 17:55:21]
Link= [http://www.something.com]
SINCE= [3] days."
```

i have a problem in reading this information from the string `addressString` and inserting it into an sqlite tabel so this is the information that im suppose to read i should only extract the text that is between brackets so the table should look like this

`BOOKNO, FROM, TO, LINK, SINCE`

those are the five columns that i need to insert into my table so im using indexof() to extract whats between the brackets
and my first row should only contain

```
1,2011-02-28 07:00:52,2011-03-17 07:01:02,http://www.example.com,5
```

second row

```
2,011-03-01 17:55:15,2011-03-30 17:55:21,http://www.something.com,3
```

and i need to insert the first 5 columns and loop again to insert the next five `addressString` contains all the above information and its read as one string 
and this is the code im using to read it

db.open();
        long idx;

```
    String lines[] = {addressString};
    String fields[] = new String[lines.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

        for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
        int be = lines[i].indexOf('[');
        int e = lines[i].indexOf(']');
        fields[i] = lines[i].substring(be+1, e);
    }
        idx = db.insertTitle(fields[0],fields[1],fields[2],fields[3],fields[4]);
        }
```

so what am i doing wrong in this code and how to make it work .....??

hi to all again i've been playing around with my code and when i try to show the output on the screen with this code i get only number 1 on the screen it does not read all the text
that is in address string

```
if (addressString != "didn't read titels"){
        String lines[] = {addressString};
        String fields[] = new String[lines.length];     
for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                int be = lines[i].indexOf('[');
                int e = lines[i].indexOf(']');
                fields[i] = lines[i].substring(be+1, e);
                myLoutputText.setText(fields[i]);
    }
```

so.. why is it only reading and displaying the first line which is [1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of lines.length. Looks like that it is returning 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling db.insertTitle, did you mean to use db.insert ?